# On a button click, create a new window and display content of an array in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array, windows-forms-designer

I have a main GUI in where I add data, in 12 columns. Each data is on one row as it comes in. This data is pushed into an array which is accessible globally. The array is dynamic 2D, growing each time I enter a set of data.

I wish to have a button that, when pressed, displays all the currently available data held in the array. If I can edit it then it's a step further, but at the moment I just need to be able to view the contents of my array.

My code is long as there are many buttons, listboxes doing different things. If needed, I can mail my code.

---

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Form2.Fm2 = new Form2();
    Form2.Fm2.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged();  
    if (Form2.Fm2 == null) {
        Form2.Fm2.Show();
    }
    else {
        Form2.Fm2.Show();
        Form2.Fm2.BringToFront();
    }  
}
```

In the above, I want to pass values of my 2D array into the Listbox on Form2. Is this the correct methodology or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the constructor of your display form to take the array, and then populate is a ListView or another appropriate control with it.

Comment: Thanks, Im newbie-medium... could you elaborate :-)

Comment: Basically, your "new window" that you display your array in is going to be a new form. You just add a control to it that can display your data, and then change the constructor from "public DisplayForm()" to "public DisplayForm(int[] array)" or whatever type your array is. Then you populate the control on the form with the data in the array.

Comment: public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2.Fm2 = new Form2();


            if (Form2.Fm2 == null)
            {
                Form2.Fm2.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                Form2.Fm2.Show();
                Form2.Fm2.BringToFront();
            }
            button1.Enabled = true;



            Form2.Fm2.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged();  

        }